# Visual Designer for native Win32 Apps

Tags: c++, visualdesigner

i have been a C# developer for a long-time now so i have huge experience with Winforms. i wanted to start VC++ development so that i can write native apps.

I know C++ very well. The problem is i have made test projects in VS2010, Win32 Application, MFC Applications and all, it doesn't provide a Visual Designer like there is for VC# Winforms and VC++ Winforms as well. i want to have a Visual designer for Native App Development like for Win32 Apps.

- Is it possible?
- How to do it?

Answer (score 5):

There is a dialog designer for MFC.  Provided you setup your project correctly, you can use the designer to layout your MFC windows.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2711197/65358) for details.

For other libraries, there are other options, as well.  For example, [Qt Creator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools/) allows you to visually design Qt windows via Qt Designer.

Comment: @JunaidSaeed Pretty much - Qt Designer is more like Windows Forms designer - if that's what you're after, but for native dev.